# Problem changing behaviour of dynamically loaded forms (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a user input page which loads different forms with ajax depending on some options the user has. I want to save this forms data with AJAX as well, but it only works with the first form that is loaded. Once the user changes the options, and a different form is loaded, the change of the form behaviour  applied with jQuery no longer works.

I guess this is happening because the script is applying the new behaviour to the form that is currently on the page, but not to forms that are loaded later, right?

I already tried encapsulating the $('form').submit()... etc in a function and calling it everytime a new form is loaded, but it doesnt work either...

Then, how can i solve this? This is my code (some of it):

```
function showFormUpdate(month, show) {
    //actualiza el formulario por ajax
    $('#showFormWrapper').fadeOut();

    $.post("../inc/ajax-select-show.php", {month: month, show: show}, function(data){
                    $('#showFormWrapper').html(data);
                    whatIsActive ();
                    }); 
    $('#showFormWrapper').fadeIn();             
    }

function showFormsend () {
    $.post("../inc/ajax-saveshowform.php", 
        {
        activeShow: $('input#activeShow').val(),
        activeMonth: $('input#activeMonth').val(),
        everyday: $('input#everyday').val(),
        mon: $('input#mon').val(),
        tue: $('input#tue').val(),
        wed: $('input#wed').val(),
        thu: $('input#thu').val(),
        fri: $('input#fri').val(),
        sat: $('input#sat').val(),
        sun: $('input#sun').val()
        }, function(data){
            alert (data);           
                    }); 
}

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('a.changeForm').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault(); 
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('changeShow')){
            showFormUpdate($('input[name="activeMonth"]').val(), $(event.target).attr('show'));
            }
        if ($(event.target).hasClass('changeMonth')){
            showFormUpdate($(event.target).attr('month'), $('input[name="activeShow"]').val());
            }   
        });

    //this is the part that changes the functionality of the form,
    //but only works with the first loaded form
    $('.showForm').submit(function(event){          
        showFormsend ();    
        return false;           


        })
});
```

Comment: thanks for the edit @Adam. although 'dymanically' was a cool sounding word

Comment: agreed; it evoked a dynamic kind of mania; and *was* much better-sounding than 'dynamically' :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have to use the live function with your events. When you destroy/re-add items that matched a raw event function when jQuery loaded (like .click or .submit) their events are gone once they are removed.

To get around this use .live which will apply the event to all existing and future-added elements that match your selector:

```
$('a.changeForm').live('click', function(event){

$('.showForm').live('submit', function(event){
```

Comment: Great, I didnt know about the .live function. In which version of jQuery was this introduced? Or has it always been there?

Comment: It's been around since 1.3. Definitely a very useful function to know!

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery `live` event binding method - this allows you to bind events to DOM elements that haven't even been loaded yet...

e.g.

```
$('.showForm').live('submit', function() {
    showFormsend ();
    return false;
});
```

At the moment when you are binding your function to the `submit` method it is only binding it to elements that exist at that moment in time.

Answer (score 1):

If im understanding this correctly (which i'm probably not) then your adding new forms to the page using ajax and your JQuery isnt working on these new forms.

A way of fixing this would be to put this code snippet into a function:

```
function someFunction() {
    $('.showForm').submit(function(event){          
        showFormsend ();    
        return false;           
    })
}
```

And then calling that function just after you add the forms to the page.

```
$.post("../inc/ajax-select-show.php", {month: month, show: show}, function(data){
    $('#showFormWrapper').html(data);
    whatIsActive ();
    someFunction();
});
```

Might be better to add the function call in a callback of $.post or .html() if they have them.

Comment: that will work but a much cleaner and easier way of solving the problem is to use the live method as mentioned by me and methodin

Comment: looks like the .live function is a much more elegant solution to this, nice for me to learn something too. (@dormisher aye, i never knew about it but yours is much better)

Comment: I was just trying that and for some reason it doesnt work... I am going to try the .live method. thanks anyway!